Quill decoder for List[Int]
In my Scala-3 project I use the following Quill code:
val rawQuery = quote {
    (id: Int, crs: List[Int]) =>
      sql"""UPDATE caze SET results=results || $crs WHERE id=$id"""
        .as[Update[Caze]]
}
val numberOfUpdates = run(rawQuery(lift(caseId), lift(caseResultIds)))

It works, but gives me a warning, which I (probably don't fully understand and) am unable to get rid off:
A Encoder: dbContext.arrayIntEncoder[crs.type] was found for the type crs but not a decoder so this type will be treated as a value. To avoid potential problems it is preferable to define both an encoder and a decoder for all types used in Quill Queries.

I have two problems with this message: a) I don't understand how List[Int] isn't automatically handled correctly, and b) how to provide an appropriate List[Int]-decoder so that the warning goes away.

I tried to reproduce it locally and didn't get that warn. Quill already has default ArrayEncoding to encode/decode Seq[Int]. Not sure if there is some issue on how you write your class or how you setup your project. What are the versions of scala and quill you are using? Is it possible to provide a minimal reproducible example?

After your comment I upgraded quill from 4.8.0 to 4.8.5 and the warning magically went away. So, thanks very much for this idea!

I downgraded the project to quill 4.8.0 and I got the same warning. Try to dig in the code of the lib, but wasn't able to find the root cause. The warning comes from QuatMaking. Seems like in following versions
